# Xcode 4.6 error - Timed out waiting for app to launch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, error-handling, timeout

I am building an app in Release, and running on an iPhone 4s.

When I click on run, everything works well, my application even runs on the iPhone.

But after some times, I have an error from Xcode : "Timed out waiting for app to launch" while my app is still running.

How to deal with it?

Comment: can you share your app delegate's - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Check which provisioning you are using, it seems that ad-hoc provisioning cannot be used for debugging. If your problem is not solve with above instruction then also try these:

```
     Stop the app from running in Xcode;
     Delete the app from the device (or Simulator);
     Select Product > Clean from the Xcode menu;
     Close Xcode;
     Close the Simulator (or restart the device);
     Restart your computer & then check.
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer: app store provisioning profiles cannot be used either for debugging.

Answer (score 10):

Check which provisioning you're using. Make sure you are using Provisioning profile for testing app on device. If you are using Distribution profile then you will have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when I relaunch the app while it is stopped at a breakpoint or during certain crashes. If you terminate the application (by press the stop button or `Ctrl`+`.`) before relaunching the app (upon crash or sitting at a breakpoint), this will not happen as often. Otherwise you should be able to get around this by:

Stopping app
Deleting app from your device
Shutting down the device (completely shutting it off)
Then restart it

You should not have to reset your actual computer or even do a manual clean. At least this has worked for me well over a dozen times.

Answer (score 1):

It can occur if you are using a distribution profile to deploy the app on iDevice, try to change the profile to developer profile and it will run again properly